# Updating variations using WP All Import

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, wpallimport

I'm trying to import products into my woocommerce store using the "Wp All Import" plugin. So far i have succeeded in importing all the "simple products" using the plugins custom fields and mapping it to update like in [this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEhw2.jpg)

What i struggle with is the variations of products. For example we sell socks. Sock 1 has three different sizes inside the same product but as "product variations". Theese variations has unique SKU- and barcode-numbers and we sell hundreds of different items with variations so i need to use this plugin to effectively update everything.

I can edit the variations inside wordpress manually "product-by-product" and when i inspect the site to see the field-IDs of the fields i need to fill in (Ex. SKU and barcode) i can later see in the import plugin that those fields are not found.

Have anyone successfully managed to import and update product variations using this plugin? If so, i really need your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods for doing this but here is one method that we frequently use.

1. Make sure that the WP All Import - WooCommerce Add-On Pro is installed and activated in your Woo instance.
2. Create a spreadsheet, XML, CSV, etc source file with elements as
   indicated in the table below. The labels provided are suggestions
   and can be changed to whatever you prefer.
3. Create an import template (New Import)
4. Keep things simple for now during this exercise and select "Upload a File" and upload the newly created source file
5. Select Import data from this file into... "New Items"
6. For "Create New" select "WooCommerce Products" then continue to step 2 in WP All Import.
7. Select your product container type (most likely will be "node" to identify which element identifies a new item)
8. You can add filters at this point if you wish but more than a couple will cripple your import speed and likely will crash the import process
9. In the next step you can begin mapping your source file column headers to the fields in WP All Import
10. In your import template (Mange Imports) in the WooCommerce Add-On section, set the "Product Type" to "Set Product Type with XPath". This assumes that you may have both simple and variable products. If you only have variable products then you can leave the setting at "Product Type" and set it to "Variable".
11. From the source file, Map the Product_Type heading to the "Set Product Type With XPath" field.
12. Continue with the rest of your mapping.
13. In the WooCommerce Add-On go to the "Attributes" tab Map the "Attribute1_Name" to the "Name" field and map the "Attribute1_Value" field to the "Values" field then click "Advanced". Note that the Parent Product data (table below) includes the Attribute Name but not the value which will be defined in the child products.
14. In the Advanced options seelct "In Variations", "Is Visible", "Not Taxonomy" (unless you wan it to be a taxonomy item), and select "Do Not Create Terms" (again, unless you want them to be terms).

If you want to include size or additional variations, click "Add more" and do the same as above.

15. Next click on the "Variations" tab then Select "All my variable products have SKUs or some other unique identifier. Each variation is linked to its parent with its parent's SKU or other unique identifier."
16. For "SKU element for parent" map the "SKU" field
17. For "Parent SKU element for variation" map the "Parent_SKU" field
18. Select "Yes" for "Variation Enabled"
19. Select "Do not set default selections for dropdowns" (This is merely our preference-we've found that allowing a default causes confusion for the site visitor)
20. Select (optional) "Create products with no variations as simple products"
21. Select "Save variation image to the gallery"
22. In the "Images" section we typically use the "Use images currently uploaded in wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/" option and map the "Image_Filenames" column to the corresponding field and then FTP the images to that location prior to import. Note that we typically separate image names with a pipe "|" as this character is infrequently used in product data but because the markdown required to create the table below uses pipes we couldn't use them here-instead I'm opting for semicolons.

| SKU | Parent_SKU | Product_Name | Price | Product_Type | Attribute1_Name | Attribute1_Value | Attribute2_Name | Attribute2_Value | Image_Filenames |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 |  | Wool Socks | 24.99 | variable | Color |  | Size |  | image1.jpg;image2.jpg |
| 101 | 100 | Wool Socks | 25.99 | variable | Color | Blue | Size | 4-9 | image3.jpg;image4.jpg;image5.jpg |
| 101 | 100 | Wool Socks | 25.08 | variable | Color | Blue | Size | 10-12 | image6.jpg;image7.jpg |
| 102 | 100 | Wool Socks | 24.99 | variable | Color | Green | Size | 4-9 | image8.jpg;image9.jpg |
| 102 | 100 | Wool Socks | 24.99 | variable | Color | Green | Size | 10-12 | image10.jpg;image11.jpg |
| 103 | 100 | Wool Socks | 29.99 | variable | Color | Red | Size | 4-9 | image12.jpg;image13.jpg |
| 103 | 100 | Wool Socks | 29.00 | variable | Color | Red | Size | 10-12 | image14.jpg;image25.jpg |
| 200 |  | Orange Shoe Laces | 4.25 | Simple |  |  |  |  | image30.jpg;image31.jpg |

What the above structure does is create a unique item/SKU for each line. Then with the Parent_SKU we map the appropriate items to their parent.

One more note about the table above: I've added a simple product to the table so you can see how it would be configured if you had a source file that contained both simple and variable products as this is a common occurrence in eCommerce. Not that it and the Parent Product do not have a "Parent_SKU" defined.

Answer (score 1):

now wpai PRO version has options to add variant to existing product,
has 2 options matching by parent sku (custom field) or by title[image: import matching]
its neat option because formerly wpai use their import table history

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem in new woocommerce versions, all import should upgrade there addon version fixes